# how to pass the docker image sha in GitHub actions

Tags: github-actions

In the old GitHub actions, I can get the image sha in the second step, the code like this:

```
- name: Build image push to aliyun
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v1
  with:
    registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
    username: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }}
    tags: ${{ github.sha }}
    file: Dockerfile
    repository: reddwarf-pro/pydolphin
    path: '.'

- name: deploy to cluster
  uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
  with:
    config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
    command: set image --record deployment/pydolphin-service pydolphin-service=registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/pydolphin:${{ github.sha }} -n reddwarf-pro
```

in the step `deploy to cluster`, I can get the sha in the prev step generate. Now I upgrade the first step from v1 to v2 like this:

```
- name: Build image push to aliyun
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
  with:
    registry: ${{ secrets.ALI_DOCKER_HUB_REGISTRY }}
    username: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_NAME }}
    password: ${{ secrets.ALIYUN_DOCKER_REPO_USER_PASSWORD }}
    tags: ${{ github.sha }}
    dockerfile: Dockerfile
    repository: reddwarf-pro/chat-server
    path: '.'

- name: deploy to cluster
  uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
  with:
    config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
    command: set image --record deployment/chat-server-service chat-server-service=registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/chat-server:${{ github.sha }} -n reddwarf-pro
```

the second step could not get the correct sha from step 1 any more. why did this happen? is it possible to fixed this issue? In GitHub action, the first step log:

```
#9 exporting to image
#9 exporting layers
#9 exporting layers 9.3s done
#9 writing image sha256:d50f982905da16a31b64fa91ef9955c4c2e1019974cddd7a6c7b05cfe0789200 done
#9 naming to docker.io/library/7ad5bdb63555eac101ffc3711ba82de5bb52d581 done
#9 DONE 9.3s
ImageID
  sha256:d50f982905da16a31b64fa91ef9955c4c2e1019974cddd7a6c7b05cfe0789200
  Warning: The `set-output` command is deprecated and will be disabled soon. Please upgrade to using Environment Files. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-11-github-actions-deprecating-save-state-and-set-output-commands/
Digest
Metadata
```

the second step log output:

```
/usr/bin/docker run --name c0442f8d4e01d916642abb4db7160f2ac546f_826e75 --label 6c0442 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "INPUT_CONFIG" -e "INPUT_COMMAND" -e "INPUT_VERSION" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/chat-server/chat-server":"/github/workspace" 6c0442:f8d4e01d916642abb4db7160f2ac546f  "latest" "***" "set image --record deployment/chat-server-service chat-server-service=***/reddwarf-pro/chat-server:7ad5bdb63555eac101ffc3711ba82de5bb52d581 -n reddwarf-pro"
using kubectl@v1.26.3
Flag --record has been deprecated, --record will be removed in the future
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve this issue? What is your **specific** question?

Comment: I totally have no idea how to resolve this issue. I am trying to write the sha into a environment variable and read it in the next step.

Comment: the overview page of the action run that also lists all warnings and errors in a list of its own (IIRC called "overview") has additional information per each error incl. a hypertext reference you should follow then.

Comment: [`github.sha`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context) represents the commit SHA and it should remain the same. [v1](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/tree/v1) of `docker/build-push-action` had [`push: true`](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/tree/v1#push) while [v2](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/tree/v2) doesn't i.e. [`push: false`](https://github.com/docker/build-push-action/tree/v2#inputs). Looks like once your image is pushed, you should be able to use it.